# How to get the events like Processed, Delivered, Bounced, Dropped using sendgrid API in Java?

Tags: java, sendgrid

We are using sendgrid API to send emails via our web portal developed using Java. We would like to capture the real time events using our portal for every mail sent using Event Webhook. Please tell us the implementation process.

We have tried using a block of code but it didn't work.

```
request.method = Method.PATCH;    
request.endpoint = "user/webhooks/event/settings";    
request.body = "{\"group_resubscribe\":true,\"delivered\":true,\"group_unsubscribe\":true,\"spam_report\":true,\"url\":\"url\",\"enabled\":true,\"bounce\":true,\"deferred\":true,\"unsubscribe\":true,\"dropped\":true,\"open\":true,\"click\":true,\"processed\":true}";    
response = sendgrid.api(request);    
String events = response.body;    
Gson gson = new Gson();    
Object obj = gson.toJson(events);
```

Comment: Whats the response body obtained ?

Comment: Obtained blank response body

Answer (score 0):

Event Notification needs to be configured in https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/mail_settings

Based on the configuration, Sendgrid sends JSON messages in real time to the URL which is provided.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uugtl.png)